# The dynamic component shows empty when rendered from another component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, dynamic-binding

I am rendering the dynamic component based on the profile the problem is when its loaded it shows the dynamic component in that not the fields which i have in the dynamic component.Below is the code that i have used.I think i am missing something to add while calling the dynamic component please help.

Below is the code that i have added in the parent component helper:

```
 doBooleanCheck :function(component,event,helper) {
  var action = component.get('c.isrendered');
 action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.myBool", response.getReturnValue());
            var boolval=component.get("v.myBool");
            if(boolval===true)
            {
                $A.createComponent(
               "c:SGDoveAuditWizard",
                    {               


                    },function (cmp, status) {
        if (component.isValid() && status === 'SUCCESS') {
            var body = component.get("v.body");
            body.push(cmp);
            alert(body);
            component.set("v.body", body);    
        }
    });
            }
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            alert('Error : ' + JSON.stringify(response.getError()));
        }
  });
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use cmp.set("v.body", ...) to set the component body, you must explicitly include {!v.body} in your component markup.